# VIM with system clipboard support

Tags: ubuntu, apt, vim

I have

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
```

which was installed with `apt`

It doesn't support the `clipboard` option. So I cannot copy some buffer contents to the system clipboard by typing `"+yy` for example.

I'm curious whether it's possible to switch my VIM to another repository that contains VIM with working `clipboard` option and update it. If yes, then how to do it? What repository, how to switch etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is that `clipboard` requires Vim to be compiled/linked against X11 libraries. (The clipboard is a GUI feature.) If this were the default configuration then Vim wouldn't be available on systems that don't also have X dependencies installed. That's a pretty big restriction given how many users don't need/want anything GUI-related (those that deploy server-only instances, for example).

I'm going based off memory of a post I saw on the Vim stack exchange site but I believe your options would be to install a different Vim package or to build Vim yourself...in both cases only IF you already have X or are willing to install it, too.

I will dig up that post and link it here soon as I find it.

---

Here we go: [Why is Vim for Debian compiled without clipboard?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13564/why-is-vim-for-debian-compiled-without-clipboard) Though it's explicitly about Debian certainly the general points apply and, given my understanding of the Debian-Unbuntu lineage, the details may be applicable, too.

Comment: Many thanks!
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
solved the problem

Comment: @ka3ak Oh, great. Glad it was that easy for you.